# How to create a GraphML repository report with Maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies, report, ivy, graphml

I want to create a GraphML repository report for all in-house made artifacts in my local Maven repository similar to the [repreport target (ant/ivy)](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/repreport.html).

so far i found:

- create mega-pom which includes just all artefacts (600+) and run dependency:tree with type=graphml on it
- use the [repreport target (ant/ivy)](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/repreport.html) directly with the maven-ant plugin

Are there other - read: more elegant and maven-like - solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [graphml output type](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html)?

```
mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file.graphml -DoutputType=graphml
```

Comment: If you really like the ivy report you could use XSLT to generate an ivy.xml from your POM :-)